Computing angle in degrees, by finding inverse of tangent manually.
Have a problem to compute $\tan^{-1}(-5/4),$ and my manual calculation was to perform: $180^{\circ} -\tan^{-1}(5/4).$
Took a right angled triangle, with perpendicular as $5,$ and base as $4.$ The two angles opposite the two perpendicular sides, i.e. the angle opposite to the perpendicular, and that opposite the base, are proportional to $5,4$ respectively. Our angle of interest is the one opposite the perpendicular axis.
Let these two angles have a $\gcd = m^{\circ},$ i.e. $9(=5+4)m = 90^{\circ} \implies m = 10^{\circ}.$
Hence, the angle of interest is $=180^{\circ} - 5m = 180^{\circ} - 50^{\circ} = 130^{\circ},$ in the counter-clockwise direction; or $5m = 50^{\circ}$ in the clockwise direction.
But, online calculator seems to show a different answer of $51.34019175^{\circ},$ in the clockwise direction, i.e. $-51.34019175^0$ .

I believe $\tan^{-1}(-5/4)= -\tan^{-1}(5/4)$.

@Soheil Please prove, or show source; and also how it satisfies the actual answer.

How do you get $m=10^\circ$.

@AngaeMT The triangle is right-angled, so the sum of the angles opposite the perpendicular, and the base is $90^0.$ The two internal angles (opposite to perpendicular, and base) are proportional to their lengths.

I dont think they are proportional to the lengths. Like in $3:4:5$ triangle, two adjacents angle are not $3:4$.

@AngaeMT Might be they are not, but the opposite angles' ratio must be very close to the ratio of their opposite sides; as the difference between my answer and the correct one is just $1.34019175^0.$

In fact, if $\theta_4,\theta_5$ are the angle with base $i=4,5$, then we only have $\tan^2\theta_4:\tan^2\theta_5=4^2:5^2$, while the actual angle ratio is about $0.753$, so your answer is just an estimation rather than the exact result.

@AngaeMT Please elaborate, as cannot see the end. The reason being that now, $\tan^2\theta_4 + \tan^2\theta_5 = 41.$ The actual needed ratio $=\tan^2\theta_5 =25/41 * 90^0.$ But, the ratio is not for angles, but need to compute the positive square root, and take the inverse of tangent again! So end is not in sight.

By definition, the range of the arctan function is $~-90^\circ < \theta < 90^\circ,~$ within a modulus of $~360^\circ.$
So, since you are taking arctan$(-5/4),~$
you know immediately that $~-90^\circ < \theta < 0^\circ,~$ within a modulus of $~360^\circ.$
Note
It is true that there is an angle $~\theta,~$ such that $~90^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ,~$ within a modulus of $~360^\circ,~$ such that $~\tan(\theta) = -5/4.$
However, by the (arbitrary) definition of the arctan function, the angle referred to in the previous paragraph should be ignored.

But, didn't get any answer for why my angle differs from the actual one by $1.34019175^0.$

@jiten : "Let these two angles have a $~\gcd = m^{\circ}," ~$ : the two angles are not integers.  In effect, you have a right triangle with legs $~4~$ and $~5,~$ and hypotenuse $~\displaystyle \sqrt{41}.~$ Apparently, you assumed that the two acute angles in the right triangle would be in proportions of $~4 ~: ~5, ~$ which is simply not true.  As a simple example, the legs of a 30-60-90 right triangle are in proportion of $~1 ~: ~\sqrt{3},~$ while the angles are in proportion of $~1 ~: ~2.$  ...see next comment.

@jiten Sometimes, when the two legs of a right triangle are almost equal, the proportion of the legs will be close to the proportion of the angles.  You should ignore this, since your whole approach is invalid.

Then is there any way of getting answer manually, else what is the method used for calculators?

@jiten I don't know much about this.  I suspect that there is a taylor series for the arctan function, which will allow you to get a numerical approximation.  However, the tried and true method is simply to use the calculator to compute arctan(5/4), and then reason analytically, that you must have $~-90^\circ < \theta < 0^\circ.$  You can't really trust calculators to respect the arbitrary definition of the arctan function.
